# Objective-C Parent Child Pointers and their relationship

Tags: objective-c

I have a parent class

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@end
```

And a child class

```
@interface Child : Parent
@end
```

In general, we can store child object in parent pointer like this

```
Parent *p = [Child alloc]init];
```

I was surprised to know that when I store parent object in child pointer like this

```
Child *c = [[Parent alloc] init];
```

Although compiler gives warning "Semantic error incompatible pointers" but when I run it works like first case. I am unable to understand why runtime is allowing this to work?

Answer (score 6):

You don't say why you are surprised by the behaviour, but one possibility is the difference between *static* and *dynamic* method lookup and typing.

First note that with *inheritance* wherever you have a `Parent` reference you may actually have a `Child` one - the latter can do everything the former can and may be substituted for one.

Now in many object-oriented languages, for example C++, variable typing and method lookup is based on the static (i.e. declared) types. So for example in C++ your variable `c` is assumed to be an instance of `Child` and when a method is called on `c` the C++ compiler determines what method to call based on this alone. Therefore assigning an instance of `Parent` is **unsafe** - such an instance does not have the methods of `Child` and disaster will surely result. You can make the assignment safe in C++ using a cast:

```
Parent *p;
Child *c;
...

c = (Child *)p;
```

The cast will check at runtime whether the object referenced by `p` is a `Child` (or any class which inherits from `Child` etc.) and produce an error if not. As this is done at runtime it is usually wrapped within a conditional which first checks whether `p` is a `Child`.

However in Obj-C method lookup is done *dynamically* at runtime based on the actual type of a referenced object and not on the type of the variable which references it. As a result of this if your `c` variable contains a reference to a `Parent` and you try to invoke a `Child` method you will get a runtime error (which will be a clean one, in the C++ case your code will probably just malfunction and/or blowup).

This dynamic nature of Obj-C makes it easy to miss a lot of programming errors, with them only becoming apparent when the code is run - and as it is very hard to test an application completely, after the code is shipped to customers. Therefore the Obj-C compiler does as much type checking as it can to help minimise the number of errors left to appear at runtime. However, again because of the dynamic nature, it will sometimes only *warn* rather than report an *error* and refuse to compile - as it did in your example.

The solution in Obj-C is the same as for C++ above - use a cast to state the object must be a certain type and protect it with a conditional:

```
Parent *p;
Child *c;
...

if([p isKindOfClass:[Child class]) // we need a Child
{
   c = (Child *)p;
  ...
}
else
{  // handle p not being a Child
   ...
}
```

The above intentionally does not discuss the relative advantages and disadvantages of *dynamic* vs. *static* , you'll do better reading that from a good book.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for this is pretty simple. Child objects are guaranteed to implement all the methods implemented by Parent, because Child is a subclass of Parent. So, there's no concern that calling a particular Parent method on an object of type Child will cause an exception. However, Parent objects do not necessarily implement all the methods implemented by Child. So later method calls (message sends to) `c` might cause an exception. The compiler doesn't know that `c` is not a Child object, since that's its declared type. Essentially, this is the once place where the compiler has a chance to warn you that what you're doing might be wrong.

The runtime is a different matter entirely. At runtime, object pointers are the same. So, there's no reason you can't store a (reference to a) Parent object in a pointer declared in the source code as type Child*. You usually shouldn't do that, for the reasons mentioned above. As long as you only call method defined by Parent, it won't cause a problem, but if you try to call a Child-specific method, you'll get a runtime exception.

In short, let the compiler help you catch errors by typing your variables as strictly as you can. It's fine to store a Child object in a variable typed Parent if you only intend to use its functionality defined by Parent. If you truly need an generic/untyped object variable, you can use `id`. In that case, you can bracket method calls with `if ([object resondsToSelector:@selector(theMethodName:)])` if you're not sure whether the object in question implements a given method.

Answer (score 2):

It works because the `init` method is declared to return an `id`, not a `Parent*` or a `Child*`.  The `id` type can be implicitly converted to any object pointer type.

You get a warning because the compiler knows that an `alloc`/`init` sequence usually returns a pointer to the type that received the `alloc` message.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume runtime is allowing it to work, in the same way you can assign a NSMutableArray to an NSArray. You are allocating an instance of the superclass Parent to Child, which would be unnecessary since Child already is inheriting parent.

Comment: Although runtime doest not complain just for assigning parent object to child pointer, but if you invoke a method that is defined in Child class and not in Parent, it will crash. So even though the pointer is of child, but the actual object is of Parent which does not have the method. Compiler will compile without issue because for compiler pointer is of Child and Child has that method. This all makes sense except why runtime is allowing event the pointer assignment, but again that is what Objective-c dynamism comes into picture!

Answer (score 1):

It "works" because of the way Objective-C actually handles messages passed to objects. Technically, you could treat all your pointers as NSObject and your program would run exactly the same way, because in the end a call like [myObject someMessage] is compiled down to a selector lookup on the object myObject points to (whatever it may be!), and then a call to that selector (if it is handled by the real object)'s implementation. There's a set of C functions in objc.h (IIRC) that can be used to do this work yourself - the compiler is basically translating message passing using the [ ] syntax into these C function calls.